# Using a class as props in a react native component

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, flowtype, es6-class, es6-modules

I'm learning react (coming from a native iOS/Swift background) and I'm a bit confused about something I can't get to work.

I have a component that accepts props, so I figured I would write a class to model those props:

```
class HeaderProps {
  text: string;
  constructor(headerText:string) {
    this.text = headerText;
  }
}

// Make a component
const Header = (props:HeaderProps) => {

  const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <View style={viewStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>{props.text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

and I'm exporting from my component like so:

```
export {Header, HeaderProps};
```

I'm then importing it:

```
import {Header, HeaderProps} from './src/components/header';

// Create a component
const App = () => ( <Header headerText={ new HeaderProps('Album') } />);
```

No text is appearing in my component.

If I just pass a string through as props it works fine, can't think of any reason why sending a class through wouldn't work.

I'm using flow type to declare the types of my arguments, not sure if that might be causing any issues.

A point in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: `<Header text="Album" />` is very different from `<Header headerText={ new HeaderProps('Album') } />`. You might want to try `<Header { ... new HeaderProps('Album') } />`

Comment: I think you're making it way more complicated that it needs to be, you can simply pass the string 'Album' or an object with multiple values, can't think of a scenario where you ever have to pass a class as a prop.

Comment: Also you're defining the prop as `headerText`, so you would have to call it as `props.headerText.text`